# Add current date with XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date, compiler-errors, xmlgregoriancalendar

I want to enter today's date with XMLGregorianCalendar but I don't know how to declare it in my code:

I have tried this code:

```
    GregorianCalendar ahora = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    XMLGregorianCalendar fecha = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(ahora);
```

But the problem is `newInstance` because is undefined:

> The method newInstance() is undefined for the type DatatypeFactory

I need to get it on this set:

```
alsb.setFrom(...)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me and just produced an `XMLGregorianCalendar` of `2020-04-13T16:16:04.660Z`. Please paste your error message into the question (and also into your search engine…).

Comment: Your code works. See the [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/lfj6wz), after copy-pasting from your Question. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: By the way, you are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Use `Instant.now()`

Comment: How is Spring related to this? If not related, edit your tags to suit.

Comment: @BasilBourque I just need to get today's date (2020-04-14). My problem was new Instance since Eclipse was not able to import or create.

Comment: @Bufank85 To capture the current date as seen in UTC: `LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )`

Comment: @BasilBourque Eclipse returns The method newInstance() is undefined for the type DatatypeFactory, I tried Instant.now and couldn't do it either

Comment: Which `DatatypeFactory` have you imported? Please show your import statement/s. I firmly believe that `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory` has had a `newInstance` method since it was introduced in Java 5.